# Understanding stride and offset when interleaving attributes in a vertex buffer

Tags: java, opengl

I don't seem to be able to wrap my head around interleaving vertex attributes.
I'm trying to pass 3 attributes to my compute shader: position, velocity, and the number of times it has bounced off something. The code worked just fine before I added the `nbr_bounce` attribute. Now the data seems to not be aligned as I'm imagining it.

Creates the interleaved list of floats:

```
class ParticleSystem {
    FloatList particleAttribList = new FloatList();
    float[] particlesBuffer;
    FloatBuffer fbParticles;
    int numOfParticles;
    ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
    ComputeProgram computeProgram;
  
    ParticleSystem(int count) {
  
      numOfParticles = count;
      for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        Particle p = new Particle();
  
        p.pos.x = random(-1, 1);
        p.pos.y = random(-1, 1);
        p.vel.x = 0.01;
        p.vel.y = 0.01;
  
        particleAttribList.append(p.pos.x);
        particleAttribList.append(p.pos.y);
        particleAttribList.append(p.vel.x);
        particleAttribList.append(p.vel.y);
        particleAttribList.append(p.nbr_bounces);
      }
      
      particlesBuffer = new float[particleAttribList.size()];
      for (int i = 0; i<particlesBuffer.length; i++) {
        particlesBuffer[i] = particleAttribList.get(i);
      }
  
      fbParticles = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(particlesBuffer);
      shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(gl, "vert.glsl", "frag.glsl");
      computeProgram = new ComputeProgram(gl, "comp.glsl", fbParticles);
    }
```

Passes the list of floats to the Shader:

```
  ComputeProgram(GL4 gl, String compute, FloatBuffer verticesFB) {
    this.gl = gl;

    //Load and Compile the Compute Shader
    int compute_shader = shaderHelper.createAndCompileShader(gl, GL4.GL_COMPUTE_SHADER, compute);

    compute_program = gl.glCreateProgram();
    gl.glAttachShader(compute_program, compute_shader);
    gl.glLinkProgram(compute_program);

    gl.glGenBuffers(1, vbo, 0);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesFB.limit()*4, verticesFB, GL4.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    // Since the Particle struct has 2 vec2 variables + 1 int, then the stride is 16 + 4 = 20
    // position attribute (no offset)
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL4.GL_FLOAT, false, 20, 0);
    // velocity attribute (with (2*4)=8 offset)
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL4.GL_FLOAT, false, 20, 8);
    // nbr_bounces (with (2*4 + 2*4)=16 offset)
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL4.GL_FLOAT, false, 20, 16);

    ssbo = vbo[0];
    gl.glBindBufferBase(GL4.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssbo);
  }
```

Compute Shader:

```
#version 430


struct Particle{
    vec2 pos;
    vec2 vel;
    float nbr_bounces;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer particlesBuffer
{
    Particle particles[];
};

layout(local_size_x = 1024, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

void main()
{
    uint i = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;

    vec2 tmpPos = particles[i].pos + particles[i].vel;

    if(abs(tmpPos.x) >= 1.0){
        particles[i].vel.x = -1.0 * particles[i].vel.x;
        particles[i].nbr_bounces += 1.0;
    }

    if(abs(tmpPos.y) >= 1.0){
        particles[i].vel.y = -1.0 * particles[i].vel.y;
        particles[i].nbr_bounces += 1.0;
    }

    particles[i].pos += particles[i].vel;
}
```

Comment: So the stride should be 24 instead of 20? I'm still getting strange behavior. When I create 2 particles the first one seems to behave as expected but the second one only travels along the x-axis and its `nbr_bounces` variable isn't getting updated.

Comment: For f sake... the goddamn library doesn't automatically pad the data for you so I had to do it myself. But now it works :)

Comment: @HampusWeslien: This code doesn't make sense. Vertex attributes are *not used* with Compute Shaders. At all. What you're using is an SSBO, which has absolutely nothing to do with `glVertexAttribPointer` calls. Your code "works" because you're binding that buffer as an SSBO, not because of any of your vertex setup.